# Error on trying to add Private key to AWS Opsworks

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh-keys, aws-opsworks, railsapps

I am trying to set up a new rails app on AWS Opswork.

While trying to add a new app, I keep getting the error "Please provide a valid SSH key"

I have created a public-private key pair using ssh-keygen, added the public key in Github and I am trying to add the PRIVATE key in AWS Opswork page. But I keep getting the SSH key error.[image]

Please help.

Comment: NOTE: I have create the keys without using password as mentioned in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingapps-deploykeys.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that OpsWorks only accepts keys in PEM format, which is not the default on newer versions of OpenSSH. (`BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY` vs `BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY`).

Convert the key in-place by running `ssh-keygen -p -N "" -m pem -f privatekeyfile`